# javascript code doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I am trying to use three.js library which is a javascript 3d library...

So the code snippet is this:

```
var segments = 16, rings = 16;
//var radius = 50;  <-- original

// create a new mesh with sphere geometry -
// we will cover the sphereMaterial next!
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
// My read from file snippet.
$.getJSON('sample.json', function(data) {  
     var radius = data.circles.r;
     console.log(radius);


    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
       new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings),
       sphereMaterial);

    // add the sphere to the scene
    scene.add(sphere);
});
// and the camera
scene.add(camera);
```

So basically earlier this code .. the radius was hardcoded (second line) but instead of hardcoding radius.. I am reading it from json file which is following?

```
{
 "circles":

{"x":14,"y":2,"z":4,"r":20}
}
```

But it doesnt show anything? And I dont see any error in firebug as well
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: is it working for you directly, without the JSON call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `$.getJSON(...)` is asynchronous. So the order of statements is most likely

1. var scene = new THREE.Scene();
2. scene.add(camera);
3. var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(...);
4. scene.add(sphere);

If you move `scene.add(camera);` into your success function, it should work as before.

Comment: Thanks.. It doesnt work. I am getting a warning "DEPRECATED: Camera hasn't been added to a Scene. Adding it..."
What is the right way to get this thing read the data from and pass it  as a parameter?

Comment: @user2052251 What was the order before your change to `getJSON`?

Comment: Please take a look at above link.

Comment: @user2052251 Then you must move all the code up to `render(...)` into your success function, of course.

Comment: Hi.. Now I updated the json that instead of one circle there is a list of circles and it fails again... can you please take a look at it http://jsfiddle.net/AWDg7/2/

Comment: @user2052251 I'm not familiar with three.js, but I can imagine, that you should create only one scene. I pulled out `renderer, camera, scene` before the for loop. Maybe `sphereMaterial` and `pointLight` belong outside the loop too. Unfortunately WebGL doesn't work here, so this is untested. Please see modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AWDg7/3/)